# permutation logic not working on List<int>

Tags: c#, algorithm

```
public class Solution 
{

    IList<IList<int>> ll=new List<IList<int>>();

    public IList<IList<int>> PermuteUnique(int[] nums) 
    {   
        PermutationUntil(nums, nums.Length, 0);
        return ll;
    }

    public void PermutationUntil(int[] l, int n, int index)
    {
        if(index >= n)
        {
            ll.Add(l.ToList());
            return;
        }

        for (int i = index; i < n; i++)
        {
            if(containsDuplicate(l, index, i))
            {
                Swap(l,index,i);
                PermutationUntil(l, n, index + 1);
                Swap(l, index, i);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Swap(int[] l, int x, int y)
    {
        int tem = l[x];
        l[x] = l[y];
        l[y] = tem;
    }

    private bool containsDuplicate(int[] arr, int start, int end) 
    {
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) 
        {
            if (arr[i] == arr[end]) 
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

PermuteUnique function return all unique permutations, but if i replace array `int[]` nums with a `List<int>` in PermuteUnique then below code does not produce expected result.
My guess is something to do with indexer but not sure. Could someone please explain why?

Comment: Not sure if that's the (only) issue, but it seems your `containsDuplicate` returns `false` when it means `true`, and vice versa.

Comment: At a guess: `ll.Add(l.ToList());` - if l is an array then `.ToList()` will create a new copy as a list, whereas if l is a list already it'll probably store a reference to the same copy of the list that you keep modifying. What does your not expected result look like?

Comment: And using `ll` stored in the class like that isn't a great idea: your code doesn't support calling PermuteUnique twice on the same instance of the class, because it doesn't reset `ll` in PermuteUnique, nor does it support two different threads running different PermuteUniques at the same time on the same object, because they will both try and write to the same `ll` and clash.

Comment: @Rup I used to believe that, but the source code for LINQ does not take into account whether it's already a list or not

Comment: Let me rephrase my question. This is not production code. I was doing coding on code practice site. sample Input: [1,1,2] and sample Output: [  [1,1,2],  [1,2,1],  [2,1,1]] . But if you call the function PermuteUnique by passing a List<int>  instead of array. It does not gives correct output.  So if you change some thing like   PermutationUntil(List<int> l, int n, int index)  and Swap(List<int> l, int x, int y)  and  containsDuplicate(List<int> arr, int start, int end) . Then output is not as expected.

Comment: What does the output look like in that case? Are there still three permutations generated? Do they still all have 1s and 2s? Are they all (as in my hypothesis) the same?

Comment: Your implementation of containsDuplicate does not check if any two elements of the array are duplicate. it only checks if the last element of the array is duplicate.